# My collapse menu opens two times on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I'm using Bootstrap's collapse. When I load the page, the menus are open by default. So when I click it to collapse for the first time, it jumps and stays open. But when I click it again, the collapse works fine.

I think there's something going on in the calling of functions and whatnot but I don't know where to look for it. I'm working on Grails, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Where are your code samples? Did you even try to fix it yourself?

Comment: The thing is, when I tried running my codes on fiddle, it works fine. But if you want to check, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/6gWz2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also add `in collapse` class to your menu content:

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gWz2/1/

Why it is happening is, when you click to the header, it looks to the menu content for if it has class `in collapse`. If it hasn't, script thinks that menu content is closed and tries opening by adding class. After that, everything works as expected.

Comment: i can't seem to change the direction of my arrows whenever the menu is collapsed, ever since i put the in collapse class. could you kindly help me?